# How to access specific elements in a list of lists to do the np.mean function?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Suppose we want to use the three files data1.csv, data2.csv and data3.csv. Your function should then take a list of the filenames and return the following:

```
array([[ 11.   11.9  13. ]
       [  9.5   6.8   9.4]
       [  7.2  11.1  12.5]
       [  8.8   7.3   9.2]
       [ 16.6  10.6  10.3]])
```

For example, the 11.0 in the top-left cell is the mean of 7.98631, 12.65900, and 12.47115 (rounded to 1 decimal place). These values are from the first row and column of each CSV file.

I`ve put the files together in a list, but i don't know how to make function np.mean in the first elements of each list inside the main list, and then the second of each and so on. Could someone help me?

MY CODE incomplete =(:

```
    import numpy as np
    
    def mean_datasets(argumentos):
        lista = []
        while int(len(lista)) < int(len(list(argumentos))):
            for files in argumentos:
                dados_txt = np.loadtxt(files, delimiter=',')
                lista.append(dados_txt)
            print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `l1`, `l2`, and `l3` are your arrays loaded from the text files. Make a list out of them (your `lista`), convert to a 3D numpy array, and simply calculate the mean along the new (first) dimension:

```
np.array([l1, l2, l3]).mean(axis=0)
```

Or

```
np.array(lista).mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: thaaaaanks a lot!!!! It was exactly what I needed! :D